# Changing complete lists of content in Combo Boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox

In my program I have a `comboBox` and a `listBox`. The `listBox` is full of different commands. The `selectedItem` and contents of the `comboBox` depend on which command is selected. The `selectedItem` in the `comboBox` stays selected for that command. For example, when the user has content selected in the `comboBox` and they switch to a different command, and then switch back, the same item will still be selected in the `comboBox`.

Because the `comboBox` gets populated with different items depending on which command is selected should I make an `ObservableCollection` for each set of items? I'm only allowed to bind the `ItemsSource` to one thing, so how would that work?

If that's not the right approach please advise. If this isn't clear enough, please let me know.

Thanks!

Here's a sample of what my program will look like:

Then, if command 2 is selected, the list in the combo box might be a, b, c, d, e, for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate ObservableCollection for each listbox command.

When the user selects a new listbox command, set the comboBox.ItemsSource to the appropriate ObservableCollection.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: My only question then is how do I reference the `comboBox`?

Comment: In your .xaml, give the combo box a name when you define it:  <ComboBox x:Name="_comboBox_commandOptions"...../>  Then, in your code-behind, you can directly access _comboBox_commandOptions.ItemsSource  whenever you want.

Comment: I thought that it wasn't correct to edit view items in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the contents of the `combobox` are tied to the selected item in the `listbox`.  Without knowing any more of the details, seems like your business object would be a “Command” object that contains an `ObservableCollection` of “SubCommand”? objects.  Your application would then contain an `Observablecollection` of “Command” objects.  The `listbox` would be data bound to the "Command" objects list, and the `combobox` would be bound to the selected items "SubCommand" collection.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're looking for a Master / Detail structure here:

Data Items:

```
public class MyCommandDefinition
{
    public string DisplayName {get;set;}

    public List<MyParameter> Parameters {get;set;}

    public Parameter SelectedParameter {get;set;}
}

public class MyParameter
{
    public string DisplayName {get;set;}

    //Additional properties depending on your needs.
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<MyCommandDefinition> Commands {get;set;}

    public MyCommandDefinition SelectedCommand {get;set;}
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Commands"}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommand}"
         DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCommand.Parameters}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommand.SelectedParameter}"
          DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>
```

Don't forget `NotifyPropertyChanged()` in all these properties if you're going to change them programatically and expect that to be reflected in the UI.

Comment: For clarification on this, the section under Data Items... is that supposed to go in the Model?

Comment: @Ericafterdark yep. The term "Data Items" in WPF refer to the items of a collection that is usually assigned as the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl (such as a `ComboBox`)

Comment: okay, that makes sense. One thing that confuses me is the way that data is bound to the `comboBox`. Where do I create the collections that are displayed in the `comboBox`?