# How to change the itemsSource of a ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to change the `itemsSource` of a `comboBox` at run-time. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169031/changing-complete-lists-of-content-in-combo-boxes) I was told to do, `comboBox.itemssource...`. That would be okay if all I needed to do was create a new `comboBox` and then call the command on it. However, I need to perform this operation on a `comboBox` that already exists in my User Control through xaml. In that case, how would I reference it? I know how to bind to properties in the control, but in this case I would need to get the whole control. Am I over-thinking it? What is the best way to do what I'm thinking?

This how I am currently switching the Collections in the `comboBox` (This is all at the model level):

```
//Property for Combo Box List
public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxList
{
    get { return _comboBoxList; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _comboBoxList)) return;
        _comboBoxList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ComboBoxList");
    }
}

public string SelectedCommand
{
    get { return _selectedCommand; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedCommand);

        if (SelectedCommand == "String Value")
        {
            ComboBoxList = new ObservableCollection<string>(newList);
        }
    }
}
```

The collections switch when using this implementation, but the `selectedItem` in the `comboBox` doesn't stick. For example, when I click on a different command and then switch back, the box no longer has a `selectedItem`.

**UPDATE**

I have a property called `selectedOperation` that is bound to my `comboBox`. It contains a simple getter and setter, with a `NotifyPropertyChange`. This makes it so that the `selectedItem` in the box stays selected. BUT, if the user clicks on a different command and selects a different item in the `comboBox`, that new item takes it's place. I need to be able to have a `selectedItem` for each collection that the `comboBox` holds.

For example:

Let's say there are 2 commands in the `listBox`, A and B. Each create a different collection in the `comboBox`. A creates a collection of numbers, and B creates a collection of names.

For command A the user selects 5. When A is selected the `comboBox` should display 5 as it's `selectedItem`. A -> 5

For command B the user selectes Roger. When B is selected the `comboBox` should display "Roger" as it's `selectedItem`. B -> Roger

Currently, the `comboBox` does not remember it's `selectedItem` when the user switches between commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather use a `DataContext` and update that source than manually updating a `ComboBox.ItemsSource`property.

This way there would be no need to know about the controls at all.

Here is a small example :

When the user clicks the button, you just take care of updating your data, not the controls presenting it.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="Window1">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window1}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Some data 1</Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_1">Some data 2</Button>
            <ListBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"></ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
        {
            get { return _collection; }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _collection.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                _collection.Add("method 1 item " + i);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  _collection.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                _collection.Add("method 2 item " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to use a new collection instead of removing items, you will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the collection.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
        {
            get { return _collection; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _collection)) return;
                _collection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] {"1", "2"});
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] {"3", "4"});
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the `[CallerMemberName]` saves you from adding the property name each time you invoke the invocator but it's only for .NET 4.5 if I remember correctly.

If you are not under .NET 4.5 then you'll have to put `OnPropertyChanged("Collection")` instead.

Reference : [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Also, update `Collection` with a new collection, not `_collection` otherwise your UI won't be notified.

**EDIT 2**

You need to track the selected item according the collection used.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="Window1">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Some data 1</Button>
            <Button Click="Button_Click_1">Some data 2</Button>
            <ListBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication10
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyCustomCollection1 = new MyCustomCollection<string>(new[] {"a", "b"});
            MyCustomCollection2 = new MyCustomCollection<string>(new[] {"c", "d"});
        }

        public MyCustomCollection<string> MyCustomCollection1 { get; set; }

        public MyCustomCollection<string> MyCustomCollection2 { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = MyCustomCollection1;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = MyCustomCollection2;
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        private T _mySelectedItem;

        public MyCustomCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
        {
        }

        public T MySelectedItem
        {
            get { return _mySelectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _mySelectedItem))return;
                _mySelectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySelectedItem"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are clearing what's in the collection and then adding a new collection. Will this be able to store the selected item in data even when a new list is put in it's place

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code to show you how to replace the collection with a new one, basically you just need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for it.

Comment: I like this answer, however there is stil one more problem that I am experiencing while using it. Please checkout my question.

Comment: Not sure about what you're trying to do in SelectedCommand ... anyway you need to track the selected item if you want it to be selected. If you want a better answer then provide more details of what you're (generally) trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am in `SelectedCommand` because the collection in the `comboBox` changes depending on the command selected in the `listBox`. I've updated my question to further explain. Please have a look.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38808/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-aybe)

Answer (score 0):

try changing the collection via style using some trigger (can be any trigger data/event) here is an example:

```
<Style x:Key="MySelectItemSourceStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Collection1}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeValue}" Value="SecondCollection">
          <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Collection2}" />
       </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```