# How to use Selected Item in a Custom Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, observablecollection, selecteditem

I have a program where I change the collection of items displayed in a `comboBox`. I've talked about it before in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189623/how-to-change-the-itemssource-of-a-combobox-in-c-sharp). Anyway, I am using a custom collection right now because `observableCollection` doesn't have a `selectedItem` property. The custom collection has a `selectedItem` property in it, but I am just unsure how to set it so that the data is saved.

**Custom Collection Class**

```
public class MyCustomCollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private T _mySelectedItem;

    public MyCustomCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }

    public T MySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _mySelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _mySelectedItem)) return;
            _mySelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySelectedItem"));
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel - Where I change the collection in the `comboBox` and set the `selectedItem` for each collection**

```
//Property for the selected command in the LIST BOX
//**For clarity: the collection in the comboBox is changed based on what is
//selected in the list box
public string SelectedCommand
{
    get { return _selectedCommand; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedCommand);

        if (SelectedCommand == "1st Collection of type A")
        {
            ComboBoxEnabled = true;
            ComboBoxList = new MyCustomCollection<string>(collectionA);
            //collectionA.MySelectedItem = ??(What would I put here?) 
        }
        if (SelectedCommand == "2nd Collection of type A")
        {
            ComboBoxEnabled = true;
            ComboBoxList = new MyCustomCollection<string>(collectionA);
            //collectionA.MySelectedItem = ??(What would I put here?)
        }
    }
}
```

How would I assign a value to `MySelectedItem` for each new collection that I create and add to the `comboBox`? This will make it so that whenever I switch to a different collection in the `comboBox`, the `selectedItem` will be displayed.

**UPDATE**

My collections are now set as `ObservableCollection<string>`.

XAML for `ListBox` and `ComboBox`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Model.CommandList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedCommand}" ... />

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ComboBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedOperation}"  ... />
```

**New `SelectedCommand` property under `ListBox`:

```
public string SelectedCommand
{
    get { return _selectedCommand; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedCommand);

        switch (SelectedCommand)
        {
            case "Collection A":
                {
                    ComboBoxList = CollectionA;
                    break;
                }
            case "Collection B":
                {
                    ComboBoxList = CollectionB;
                    break;
                }
        }
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => ComboBoxList);
    }
}
```

**The program still does not keep the `selectedItem` that is selected for each collection.** I must be forgetting, or not understanding something.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you decided to implement a custom `ObservableCollection`. You can bind your `ComboBox` to a collection as well as the selected Item `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding someCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding someItem}"/>`

Comment: I know that, and that works. But, the `comboBox`'s collection and `selectedItem` depend on what command is selected in the `listBox`. So the `selectedItem` is not dependent on one collection for each window that it exists.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want a `ComboBox` that when you change it's collection (I assume by selecting some item in the listbox), it's `SelectedItem` becomes ... what?

Comment: Yes. The `selectedItem` will be whatever the user selects. So it will be nothing at first.

Comment: Then just bind your comboBox to a collection, bind it a selectedItem, and on the change command of your listbox change the collection ... Hold on I'll post an example code in an answer ...

Comment: I think I'm already doing that. My `comboBox` has a collection called `ComboBoxList` and a `selectedItem` called `SelectedOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom collection to bind a selected item. 
Here is an example of how to accomplish this:

```
   <StackPanel>
        <!-- your listbox -->
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox">
            <sys:String>Fruits</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Vegetables</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Others</sys:String>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listbox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>

        <!-- your combo box -->
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

xaml contains a `ListBox` with items (in this example, simple strings) and a command `SelectionChangedCommand` that invokes whenever the selection in the list gets changed.

here is the *ViewModel*

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    // your collections
    private ObservableCollection<string> fruits;
    private ObservableCollection<string> vegetables;
    private ObservableCollection<string> others;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        fruits = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "Apple", "Banana"
            };
        vegetables = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "Tomato", "Cabbage"
            };
        others = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "Pizza", "Steak"
            };

        SelectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(item =>
            {
                // When user selects item in the listbox change the collection of your comboBox
                switch (item)
                {
                    case "Fruits":
                        {
                            Items = fruits;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Vegetables":
                        {
                            Items = vegetables;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Others":
                        {
                            Items = others;
                            break;
                        }
                }

                // Raise property change to make combobox update
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
            });               
    }

    // the collection currently displayed in the comboBox
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    // The selected item of the combobox
    public string CurrentItem { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<string> SelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel contains:

1. Multiple collections as private members (*fruits*, *vegetables* and *others*)
2. `Items` which is a collection property representing the current items of the `ComboBox` based on the selection in the ListBox`.
3. `CurrentItem` property binded to the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox`.
4. `SelectionChangedCommand` that when invoked, changes the collection based on the given parameter (the selected item in the `ListBox`).

Note that this example uses [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework but you can achieve this with any [MVVM framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using) that supports Commands.

If you are not using any framework, just treat the code in the "Command" as the code that gets executed whenever the selection item of the `ListBox` gets changed (However you've implemented that).

Hope this helps

Comment: You must be using some kind of framework because I'm just using C#->WPF. I don't get `Interaction` in my xaml.

Comment: the so-called `SelectionChangedCommand` makes me confused, it's in fact an `event handler` called `SelectionChangedEventHandler`.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Yes. Sorry for not mentioning it. I use [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework. if your'e not using any framework (which you should by the way), Just put the code of the command in your `SelectedCommand` setter which I assume gets called whenever the user changes the selecteItem of the ListBox

Comment: Yes. Okay, that makes more sense, that's where I was trying to deal with it, as you can see in the question.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Are you able to detect a selection change of your `ListBox` in your `viewModel`?

Comment: If I really wanted to I could proxy the property. I'm actually doing the work in the model

Comment: @Ericafterdark Not sure what you mean by _proxy_, but I gotta say it sounds like your'e making something that can be fairly easy using [MVVM frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using), FAR more complicated for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Omribitan I have the collection changing through a switch statement like you have, but I think I'm missing what you're doing with `currentItem`, bound to `selectedItem` in `comboBox`. The `selectedItem` of the `comboBox` appears blank whenever I click on a command that I already set the `selectedItem` for.

Comment: @Ericafterdark Upload you xaml

Comment: On top of this, wouldn't I have to create a new instance of the collection every time I display one in the `comboBox`? -- What if there are two commands that give the `comboBox` the same collection?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39018/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-omribitan)